# Debug JVM Crash (How do I find the error in the underlying C code?)

Tags: java, c, raspberry-pi, swig

I get the following crash report when running some SWIG generated JNI code.

[hs_er_pid4665.log](https://gist.github.com/tobyweston/4ba95965526253d818af)

I suspect the C code is doing something naughty as I can see the C method `show` is causing the problem;

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libws2812-RPi.so+0x4d84]  show+0x308
```

But I'm not sure how to pursue it further.

The C code is on [github](https://github.com/tobyweston/unicorn-hat/tree/master/ws2812) along with the JNI [SWIG generated Java classes](https://github.com/tobyweston/unicorn-hat/tree/master/src/main/java/bad/robot/unicorn/neopixel).

I'm using SWIG 2.0.7 and compile everything like this;

```
swig -java -package bad.robot.unicorn.neopixel ws2812-RPi.i

gcc -fPIC -c ws2812-RPi.c ws2812-RPi_wrap.c -DPERI_BASE=0x3F000000 -DRPI2 -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/include/linux

gcc -shared ws2812-RPi.o ws2812-RPi_wrap.o -o libws2812-RPi.so
```

Thanks to `kjp` I created a core dump and running `gdp java core` then `where` gives the following? Does it help diagnose?

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x76dae8dc in raise () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#1  0x76db265c in abort () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#2  0x1b005d0a in ?? ()
#3  0x1b005d0a in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Can you see what the problem is from the error report?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the C code is doing something naughty. It is causing a SIGSEGV possibly due to some invalid memory access.
But without a core file, it is not easy to debug what is going on with the C process. So enable core dumps as mentioned in the debug log as below:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Also enable debug mode on the C compile by adding the -g flag.
Then run the process again and try to debug it with gdb.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault means the program is trying to access memory that it shouldn't, and the crash report indeed does appear to implicate your native library.  Although you could possibly reconfigure your environment to enable core dumps, if you're not prepared to sort through a dump then that doesn't really get you very far.

It would be of greater long-term value to write automated tests for your native library.  A good test suite would not only help you pinpoint this particular error, it would also help you catch any future bugs that may crop up in the library as you maintain and develop it.  Of course, if your library is of any significant size and does not already have adequate tests, then it will be a lot of work to write a comprehensive test suite.

Comment: The library is third party, as it goes, it works when run under python via SWIG but somehow the JVM isn't as forgiving.

Comment: Java vs. Python does not control whether your lib segfaults.  Given a library function that is susceptible to performing invalid memory accesses when presented with valid arguments, it is a matter of the function and its specific arguments.  Since it's a third-party library, have you considered raising the issue with the appropriate third party?

Comment: I will do yes, I'd like to have a few more clues to help them first though. Reproducing it in C for example.

Comment: Perhaps you can introduce some logging into your Java code to help you figure out what arguments may be being passed.